# How can I validate maxlength of a array of strings in mongoose schema?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
//var validate = require('mongoose-validator');
const postschema = mongoose.Schema({ 
    userName :{
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    status : {
        type : Array ,
        items : {
            type : String ,
            max: 20 ,
            required : true
        },
    },
    likes : {
        type : Array ,
        default : []
    }
},
{ timestamps :{ createdAt: 'created_at',updatedAt: 'updated_at' }}
);

postschema.path('status').validate(function(v){
    return v.length <=20;
},"The maximum length is 20 ");

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post' , postschema);
```

My validation function is not working . How can I validate my status Array of String. I want to validate each string of 20 characters

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
const postschema = new Schema({
userName :{
    type : String,
    required : true
},
  status: {
    type: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'peopleModel'
    }],
    validate: [arrayLimit, '{PATH} exceeds the limit of 10']
  }
});

function arrayLimit(val) {
  return val.length <= 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it's that easy for status use;

```
    status: [
          {
            type : String ,
            maxLength: 20 ,

          },
    ]
```